# CKEditor only allow <img> tags with certain attribute

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want CKEditor to allow everything except images tags without a specific data field. e.g. `data-test`.

I tried what the documentation says. For now not allowing all `<img>` tags.
But it still accepts all images.

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = 'img';
```

Answer (score 0):

With `config.disallowedContent = 'img'` you are removing whole `img` element from ACF. Use [extraAllowedContent](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent) to specify image element.

```js
// Clone CKEDITOR.dtd so we are not modifying CKEditor objects.
var elements = CKEDITOR.tools.object.merge( {}, CKEDITOR.dtd );

delete elements.img;

config.allowedContent: {
  $1: {
    elements: elements,
    attributes: true,
    styles: true,
    classes: true
  }
};
        
config.extraAllowedContent: 'img[!src,!data-test]';
```

You can see a working example here: https://codepen.io/jacekbogdanski/pen/gKremp

Comment: I tried it and I can still insert all images. Even those without the data-test field

Comment: You are right. I forgot about removing `img` element from `CKEDITOR.dtd`, please see updated answer.